# Datetime picker is not working in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add an input **Date Time** system in my bootstrap form. I saw some example but no is working.

Now I want to add this from this site but it also not working.

https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime" data-date="2013-02-21T15:25:00Z">
    <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        startDate: "2013-02-14 10:00",
        minuteStep: 10
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest me what should I do now??

Comment: **not working** can you explain this keyword in detail? Why it is not working? What error you are getting? Did you check logs?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using, and what version is used in the example you followed?

Comment: v3.3.7 It's just showing the input field and calendar icon but when I click no calendar is opening.

Comment: Check if there are any errors showing up in your console. It's hard to suggest anything without knowing what issue you're facing exactly

Answer (score 1):

You have given class `form_datetime` to a div. The `datetimepicker` should be applied to input text box. The url you provided also states the same.

The `form_datetime` is applied to textbox and not div.

Try as below.

```
<div class="input-append date" data-date="2013-02-21T15:25:00Z">
    <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly class="form_datetime">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        startDate: "2013-02-14 10:00",
        minuteStep: 10
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you added or included the script and CSS file for bootstrap datetimepicker?

Comment: only this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without loading cdn?